# Probability that k persons leave an elevator on exactly j out of n floors

Tags: probability, combinations

I'm trying to come up with a formula to calculate the probability that `k` persons which entered an elevator will leave on exactly `j` different floors out of `n` available floors. The decisions of the persons are independent and the probability to get off at any floor is $\frac{1}{n}$.

The extrema seem to be quite clear. So for example for 4 persons and 10 floors:

- Probability that all leave on the same level: $(\frac{1}{10})^4 \cdot 10$
- Probability that all leave on different levels: $\frac{10!}{10^4 \cdot 6!}$

For the calculation of the probabilities between these two extrema I can't find a solution. E.g. for the 4 persons leaving on 3 different floors (so two leave on the same floor) I tried the following:
$$\frac{10}{10} \cdot \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{8}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{10}$$
The idea was that the first one can choose out of 10 floors, the second one out of 9, the third one out of 8 and the last one must pick one of the already chosen three other floors. However, this underestimates the real probability.

I think [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553074/probability-that-j-persons-to-get-off-on-the-same-floor-and-k-j-persons-to) is asking a similar question, but I don't know how to compute $C_j^k$ and $A_n^{k-j+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If each person is taking an independent decision, I am presuming that people are being treated as distinct
- Choices for floors to alight = $\binom{n}{j}\equiv C^n_j$
- Now $j$ floors have to be populated with none empty.
  This can be done in $j!{k\brace j}$ ways, where the part in braces stands for Stirling numbers of the second kind (which would populate $k$ people on $j$ **identical** floors)
- Total choices for alighting $= n^k$
- finally, $ Pr = \Large\frac{\binom{n}{j}\times j!{k\brace j}}{n^k}$

____________--

**Added**

For your example of $10$ floors, $4$ people, $3$ floors alighted, it would work out to

$\Large\frac{\binom{10}3\times 3!{4\brace3}}{10^4}$

The denominator and selection of floors, of course, should be obvious, we can work out the part involving the Stirling number in a simple way to [confirm](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3%21+*+S2%284%2C3%29), as $\binom31\times\frac{4!}{2!1!1!} = 36$
[Choose floor which will have $2$][Distribute people]

and $3!{4\brace 3} = 36$

Obviously the simple way won't be suitable for a big problem, but you can keep it in mind for small ones